# Flask not finding root to / -404

Tags: python, web, flask

Hello Im new to flask and python, i tried redirecting my script to go to something.html as it was apresenting a 404 i decided to run a hello world and did not work.

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

http://localhost:5500/hello

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=         'postgre://postgres:*****@localhost/web'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Rent(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(200) , unique=True)
sug1 = db.Column(db.String(200) , unique =True)
sug2 = db.Column(db.String(200) , unique = True)
sug3 = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)



def __init__ (self,email,sug1,sug2,sug3):
    self.email = email
    self.sug1 = sug1
    self.sug2 = sug2
    self.sug3 = sug3


def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %>' % self.email


    @app.route('/hello')
    def index():
        return "Hello"



@app.route('/resumo', methods=['POST'])
def pesquisa():
    rent = Rent(request.form['email'],request.form['sug1'],request.form['sug2'],request.form['sug3'])
    db.session.add(rent)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index')) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(port=5500)
```

Comment: Is the `index()` function indented as shown?

Comment: Is @app.route('/hello') indented like that in your code or just here? It should not be indented or it will be treated like a part of the __ repr __ function

Comment: yes , as usual, python would complain if so

Comment: ok ill teste it

Answer (score 0):

If your code is similar to the one that shows you have indentation problem of the code, your code should look like the following.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgre://postgres:*****@localhost/web'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Rent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200) , unique=True)
    sug1 = db.Column(db.String(200) , unique =True)
    sug2 = db.Column(db.String(200) , unique = True)
    sug3 = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)


    def __init__ (self,email,sug1,sug2,sug3):
        self.email = email
        self.sug1 = sug1
        self.sug2 = sug2
        self.sug3 = sug3

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %>' % self.email


@app.route('/hello')
def index():
    return "Hello"


@app.route('/resumo', methods=['POST'])
def pesquisa():
    rent = Rent(request.form['email'],request.form['sug1'],request.form['sug2'],request.form['sug3'])
    db.session.add(rent)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index')) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(port=5500)
```